# Saving Django model with DateTime fields

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

Model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(blank=False, null=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    normal_price = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=4)
    available_count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
```

Now, when I'm saving it's instances the `created_at` and `updated_at` values are set properly, eg: `2016-08-21 13:13:57.585472+02`. `collection_from` value should be nearly the same as those two previous ones, but it's getting set to point to the next day, eg: `2016-08-22 01:00:00+02` which I don't get at all :). The `collection_from` value looks like that when sent by the browser: `2016-08-21 23:00`. I believe I have proper settings set up int the `settings.py` file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_TZ = True
```

So what's the problem here? How do I make Django save `collection_from` value the same way as `created_at` or `updated_at`?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that when the values for this model are retrieved, I get the correct ones - so if I the value of `collection_from` field is equal to `2016-08-22 01:00:00+02` in the database, on the output it's being converted to what the initial value was, so `2016-08-21 23:00`. So now the question changes - why the difference between `created_at` and `updated_at` fields and this one?

**EDIT2:**

I didn't think it will be necessary (as I described well enough how I supply the `collection_from` value), but here's the POST request body:

```
[{"collection_from":"2016-08-21 23:00","discount_price"
:"10","normal_price":"20","available_count":"4","name":"pizza"}]
```

And the DRF view saving it:

```
class MealsCrudView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MealSerializer
```

And the serializer:

```
class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
```

Comment: How are you saving the value in `collection_from`. Please show the full code where all you work with `collection_from`.

Comment: I don't have any special code for that. Django handles the save.

Comment: `collection_from` does not have `auto_now_add` or `auto_now` which means you must be supplying a value for that field - it cannot be populated automatically. You need to show us the code that creates an instance of the object and assigns this value.

Comment: But that's what I'm saying - there's no code. It's only a django rest framework `CreateAPIView` with no custom code. I'm sending a request to it with the `collection_from` value looking the way I described it in the question: "The collection_from value looks like that when sent by the browser: 2016-08-21 23:00"

Comment: Please, provide an info about your request. e.g. GET and POST params.

Comment: Jesus Christ! Can't anybody read these days? Look at the bottom of the question...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Meal(models.Model):
    ...
    collection_from = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...
```

instead of sending current time?